# How do I get the pressure sensitivity to work on my Ugee tablet?

Tags: windows

I have a Ugee tablet running on Windows 10 for drawing, and the stylist pen works fine on it. However, the pressure sensitivity does not work. If I place my cursor over the tablet icon on the right of my task bar, the icon disappears. In order for the pressure sensitivity to work, I have to restart my computer, but I have to do that each time. How can avoid this?

Comment: If I understand your question, pressure sensitivity works, but it stops working if yo perform a certain action, and then in order for it to work again you have to restart the system?

Comment: Not quite. Using the pen on the screen works, but the pressure sensitivity doesn't work at all. Pressure sensitivity is the amount of ink that comes out of a pen depending on how hard it is pressed against the screen (thin, thick, faded, etc.)

Comment: Any drivers specifically indicate Windows 10 support?

Comment: Hmm... I just checked on their website, and it looks like there are drivers available for each OS except Windows 10. That could be the problem.

Comment: “… the pressure sensitivity does not work.  … In order for the pressure sensitivity to work, I have to restart my computer …” but “… the pressure sensitivity doesn’t work at all.” I still don’t understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the driver, compatibility and run as administrator. Seems the driver needs admin privileges. M/S to blame again, as usual!